# Monit IF/ELSE syntax

Tags: monit

I attempting to monitor a service. My monit definition is below.

When I invoke `monit -r` I receive `/etc/monit/conf.d/authentication.monit:10: syntax error 'else'`

```
check host self with address myhost
start program = "/usr/bin/service start authentication"
stop program  = "/usr/bin/service stop  authentication"
if failed port 443 protocol https
  request /
  with timeout 5 seconds
  for 2 cycles
  then restart
if 1 restarts within 4 cycles then exec "/etc/monit/pagerduty-trigger authentication" else if passed for 2 cycles then exec "/etc/monit/pagerduty-resolve authentication"
```

All the documentation seems to indicate my syntax is correct.

I am attempting to follow the two docs

[pagerduty](https://www.pagerduty.com/docs/guides/monit-integration-guide/)

[primary docs](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is :

> IF *test* THEN *action* [ELSE IF SUCCEEDED THEN *action]

Also

The "if x restarts within y cycles then ..." statement doesn't support the "else" part: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-RESTART-LIMIT

*Else* for *restart* is a bit non-sense as there is no contrario for *restart*

I'm trying to get your logic here for the if then else actions but don't understand the *else* part.

Here you want to "stop then "start" service "authentication when https://myhost:443/ is failing two times (called T0)
Then on the next cycle, you want to run script */etc/monit/pagerduty-trigger authentication*. (called T0 + 1 cycle)
Here why *within 4 cycles* but not less like 2, bot ok.

I suppose that on the T0 + 1 + 2 cycles, if service a online again, you want to run "/etc/monit/pagerduty-resolve authentication"

One solution is to handle it at your *failed* test level with custom scripts

`if failed port 443 protocol https
    request /
    with timeout 5 seconds
    for 2 cycles
    then exec "/var/lib/monit/scripts/notifyAndExecute.sh" 
        else if succeeded then exec "/etc/monit/pagerduty-resolve authentication"`

create file */var/lib/monit/scripts/notifyAndExecute.sh* in charge of restarting and calling */etc/monit/pagerduty-trigger authentication*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are still looking at this.  I am also integrating Monit with Pagerduty.  I have one simpler example which is working.  What I note is the 'else' appears to only support "else if succeeded" .  I think it is simply a long hand version of 'else' without to ability to add a more sophisticated expression that you are attempting.

Here is my example which triggers when service ( process in monit ) does not exist and resolves when it does.

```
check process tomcat8 with pidfile /var/run/tomcat8.pid
    if not exist
    then exec "/etc/monit/pagerduty-trigger tomcat8"
    else if succeeded then exec "/etc/monit/pagerduty-resolve tomcat8"
```